# Trying to get data from a website but not coming

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import tablib


my_url = 'https://tradingeconomics.com/india/indicators'

uClient2 = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient2.read()
uClient2.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers11 = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"tab-pane"})

filename = "tradeeconomics.csv"

f = open(filename, "w", encoding='utf-8-sig')
headers = "GDP, Last, Reference,Previous,Range,Frequency\n"
f.write(headers)

for container in containers11:

    title_container = container.findAll("div",{"class":"col-md-4 col-xs-5"})


print(title_container)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need `BeautifulSoup` to get the tables.

You might want to try `pandas`.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

html = requests.get("https://tradingeconomics.com/india/indicators").text
df = pd.read_html(html, flavor="bs4")[1]
df.to_csv("trade_economics.csv", index=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: but by this methode not able to extract other table data gdp , labour, price etc

Comment: Use `df` indexing to get the table you want.